# Unable to connect to the remote server : The response ended prematurely - Exception .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I'm trying to run a WebSocket in a console app in .NET 6 and it's generating this error when opening a connection to the server running locally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a hub, you have code like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapHub<CustomHub>("/myhub");
});
```

Accordingly, the path to the hub will be as follows:

ws://localhost:7035/myhub

Obviously you just have the wrong url